Применение готовой анимации к сгенерированному 3d образу
Разрабатываю простенький 3D-редактор человеческого лица. Суть вот в чём: человек загружает в программу много фото с разных ракурсов своей головы и на выходе получает obj файл с текстурированным mesh'ем (треугольная сетка). Вроде бы всё хорошо.
Но вот дальше появилась необходимость реализовать следующую фичу: а что если теперь на сгенерированном черепе нужно, к примеру, немного вытянуть подбородок или чуть подправить нос? Имеется в виду, что нужно предоставить пользователю в приложении с помощью, например, ползунка отрегулировать эти параметры.
При этом у меня есть, так сказать, универсальная модель черепа без текстуры со скелетной анимацией (у подбородка анимация - вытягивание кости и тд).
И сама суть вопроса: а можно ли, имея только сгенерированную модель и вот эту уже сделанную универсальную модель, как-то подогнать сгенерированный череп под универсальный, чтобы на сгенерированном были все те же анимации? То есть чтобы не выходя из программы и не добавляя анимацию уже вручную. Если возможно, то по какому принципу? На ум приходит какой-то оптимизационный алгоритм, который бы как-то показывал, что на сгенерированном черепе анимация сидит почти так же, как и на универсальном. Всё же, черепа у разных людей хоть и отличаются, но не слишком сильно.
